# Android Defered DeepLink not working

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I got problem to make the FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData() function to work on android, all works well on IOS but on Android I just get *{"did_complete":true,"callback_id":"2"}* as response from Facebook, no URL.

I saw in the logcat a message from GraphRequest : *Warning: Request without access token missing application ID or client token.*

So I added the **ClientToken** in the AndroidManifest.xml and the FacebookSettings
(adding it only in the setting didn't work), OK the warning is gone, but I'm still getting the same result without url.

## Here is my code to test the deep link:

```
void Awake ()
{
    if( !FB.IsInitialized ) 
    {
        FB.Init( InitCallback );
    } 
    else 
    {
        InitCallback();
    }
}

private void InitCallback ()
{
    if( FB.IsInitialized ) 
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
        FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData( InvokeURIRecived );
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log( "Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK" );
    }
}

private void InvokeURIRecived( IAppLinkResult result )
{
    Debug.Log( "InvokeURIRecived " + result.RawResult );
}
```

## To test the deferred deep link :

- I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper
- I select my app
- I click on Test Deep Link
- I enter the deeplink: *myapp://test?id1=1&id2=test_deeplink*
- I Uninstall the app on my device
- I click on the notification just received from facebook
- I install my app from unity and launch it

Did I missed somethig ? I search on google but nobody seems to have problem using this...

## [EDIT]

I tried with the Facebook Unity SDK (v7.10.1) sample app and I got the same results.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue. Have you got any solution ???

Comment: Hi, i just edited the main thread : The problem has been solved by resetting  advertising IDs on the devices (https://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/20/how-to-reset-your-advertising-id-on-android/)

Comment: Glad you solved it, @BenjaminBOUFFIER. Feel free to post your solution as an answer. You may also accept your own answer (after a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by resetting advertising IDs on the devices. I followed the instructions found [here: How to reset your advertising ID on Android](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/20/how-to-reset-your-advertising-id-on-android/).

(This information was posted in a comment, apparently by the OP from a different Stack Overflow account. I wanted to add it as an answer to make it clear that the question has been answered.)